# angular form model of array

Tags: angular, observable

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    models: Model[];
    ngOnInit() {
        // a bunch of Observable pipes and subscriptions one of which sets the models
    }
    add(): void {
        let newModel = {...};
        this.models.push(newModel);
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form *ngIf="models" (ngSubmit)="onSubmimt()" #modelForm="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let model of models; last as isLast">
        <input name="..." [(ngModel)]="model.name" />
        <button *ngIf="isLast" (click)="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

After I put in some data into the form and click the Add button, previously entered data is all gone. I debugged it and found out that after Angular framework calls `drainMicroTaskQueue()` in `zone.js`, the data is gone.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The data is gone from the form but still exists in the model itself.

EDIT2: After each push, the view repeats the newly added model and discards the other models in the array.

Comment: can you describe some more information, what exactly you want?

Comment: @AjayOjha I have an array of objects from the server. I need to be able to update them in the form, and add more objects to this array and push them back to the server.

Comment: the problem in your code is that the array is not initialized: models: Model[]=[]; //<--equal to [], else you can not push because models are undefined

Comment: @Eliseo It is initialised in `ngOnInit`. Look at my comments there.

Comment: @Antediluvian, I don't see it. If you write models:Model[], this.models are **undefined** (yes type an array of Models, but undefined yet). So you can not make this.models.push(..). If you write models:Modeles[]=[], this.models will be an **empty array** of type models and then is correct write this.models.push(...)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add new models when you click add button - if so you're just updating the model try to push the new value for the model in the seperate array and then assign it to the models array

like this

```
add(): void {
        let anyArray: any[] = [];
        anyArray = [...this.models];
        let newModel = {...};
        anyArray.push(newModel);
        this.models = [...anyArray];
    }
```

Above method will work - If not your can try the below method too

```
add(): void {
            let newModel = {...};
            this.models = Object.Assign({}, newModel);
        }
```

Thanks Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thanks for your code sample but I didn't even try the 1st one because it looks incorrect. The 2nd gave me errors.

Comment: I think the first one will work try like this `let anyArray: any[] = this.models` and follow the code hope it works - if 2nd one is the option try assigning the models array to a another array and then push it to model array `Object.Assign([], this.models)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
The `name` attribute of the input appears the same for all the newly added model which confused Angular.